# git undo mistaken tracking branch

Tags: git, branch, git-track

i wanted to setup my local mainline branch to track origin/mainline but used the command

`git branch --set-upstream origin/mainline mainline` by mistake,

with the outcome `Branch origin/mainline set up to track local branch mainline`.

How can I fix this so local mainline tracks remote mainline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the wrong arguments order, what you want is `git branch --set-upstream mainline origin/mainline`.

see:

**-t, --track**

> When creating a new branch, set up configuration to mark the
>   start-point branch as "upstream" from the new branch. This
>   configuration will tell git to show the relationship between the two
>   branches in git status and git branch -v. Furthermore, it directs git
>   pull without arguments to pull from the upstream when the new branch
>   is checked out.
>
> This behavior is the default when the start point is a remote-tracking
>   branch. Set the branch.autosetupmerge configuration variable to false
>   if you want git checkout and git branch to always behave as if
>   --no-track were given. Set it to always if you want this behavior when the start-point is either a local or remote-tracking branch.

**--set-upstream**

> If specified branch does not exist yet or if --force has been given,
>   acts exactly like --track. Otherwise sets up configuration like
>   --track would when creating the branch, except that where branch points to is not changed.

So what your had did is creating a local branch named `origin/mainline` which tracks `mainline` branch.

Answer (score 1):

It seems git created another local branch origin/mainline and made it to track mainline. I used `git config -e` and then set `remote=origin` for mainline(origin being already defined)  and then `git branch -d origin/mainline` to delete the local branch. Seems to have addressed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the similar problem of using:

```
git branch -t origin/master
```

instead of `git branch  --set-upstream-to=origin/master` to track origin/master.

Somewhat simpler solution was: I have deleted ****local branch** Origin/master**
that was created first.

And then did: `git branch  --set-upstream-to=origin/master` succeed, because now it can detect the actual origin/master.